# Access TenantId in Model Project in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I am moving an app from single tenant to multi-tenant. In the process, I added tenantId to all the required models and updated the database (Entity Framework 5).

However, I have all the repositories that need updating. First, I don't know how to get the current user id (then tenantId) in the Model Project (not dependent on WebSecurity, no httpContext).

Second, I don't want to have to do this ugly/expensive code in all my controllers. (Get UserId, make a database call to get the tenantId, then pass that to the Repository.)

```
public class PinTypeController : BaseController
{
    private PinTypeRepository pinTypeRepo;

    public PinTypeController()
    {
        UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository();
        UserProfile user = userRepo.GetById(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
        this.pinTypeRepo = new PinTypeRepository(user.TenantId);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        vmPinType vm = new vmPinType();
        vm.NewPinType = new PinType();
        vm.PinTypes = pinTypeRepo.GetAll();
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

**Is there a better way to store the tenantId in a way that I can access it from the Model Project and all my repositories?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would decouple where the tenant id is coming from, from the rest of your code, for example you could support multiple domains where one tenant is mapped to a domain.

In my project I defined an interface

```
interface ITenantProvider
{
    Tenant Tenant { get; }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
class TenantProvider : ITenantProvider
{   
    Tenant Tenant
    {
        get
        {
            Tenant tenant = HttpContent.Current.Items["Tenant"] as Tenant;
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                string domain = GetDomain();
                tenant = TenantRepository.GetTenantByDomain(domain);
                HttpContext.Current.Items["Tenant"] = tenant;
            }
            return tenant;
        }
    }
}
```

I cache the tenant in the items-dictionary, so I can access the tenant as often as I want per request and dont get any performane issues.

If each user has a custom tenant it is not a problem, because you just have to change the interface. You could also add more complex logic, e.g. in my frontend the tenant is defined by url and in the admin-area there is a route-parameter for the tenant-id.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the type of solution that I'm looking for. So do you populate that in the global.asax session_start? And if it's parts of the httpContext, how does it get passed to the Model project?

Comment: I use unity as a dependency injection framework, but you can also create the tenant provider manually and pass it to your model. There is no need to setup anything when the session starts, you can just create a new instance and pass the tenant provider to your model, for example in the controller. The tenant is calculated once per request.

Comment: I'll have to learn about dependency injection. Something that I've been meaning to do eventually anyway. Thanks for the guidance!